# What kind of symmetry does the Galois group of an equation show between the root sets?

Tags: group-theory

I know that the Galois group of an equation on $\mathbb{Q}$ can be determined according to the rational relation determined by Vieta's theorem.

Page 393 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000006553364&d=A78F1D5CC2EECD828B780414BCA4C1AE&fenlei=13010903) also points out that these relations are to keep all polynomial relations between root sets (the result are all rational numbers) unchanged:

[image]

Taking the equation $f(x)=x^{4}-4x^{2}-5$ as an example, its four roots are $\sqrt{5}$, $-\sqrt{5}$, $i$ and $-i$ in turn.

```
f1[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := x1 + x2
f2[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := x3 + x4
f3[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := x1*x2(*Rational relations between root sets determined by Vieta theorem*)
G = SymmetricGroup[4];
sol = Select[{Permute[Inactive[f1][x1, x2, x3, x4], G],
    Permute[Inactive[f2][x1, x2, x3, x4], G], 
    Permute[Inactive[f3][x1, x2, x3, x4], 
     G]}\[Transpose], ((((Activate[#] /. {x1 -> 
            Root[#1^4 - 4 #1^2 - 5 &, 1], 
           x2 -> Root[#1^4 - 4 #1^2 - 5 &, 2], 
           x3 -> Root[#1^4 - 4 #1^2 - 5 &, 3], 
           x4 -> Root[#1^4 - 4 #1^2 - 5 &, 4]})) // 
       FullSimplify) == {0, 0, -5}) &]
FindPermutation[#, Inactive[f1][x1, x2, x3, x4]] & /@ sol[[All, 1]]
PermutationList[#, 4] & /@ %(*The group is isomorphic to the Klein's four-group and is a subgroup of group S4*)
```

From the above code, we can see that by keeping the polynomial relationship between the root sets such as $x1 + x2 = 0$, $x3 +x4 = 0$, $x1*x2=-5$, which results with rational numbers unchanged, we find the Galois group of the equation $f(x)=x^{4}-4x^{2}-5$ on $\mathbb{Q}$.

If the Galois group `G` is [solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group), then the equation $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{Q} $ is radical solvable and the group has a normal subgroup sequence $\mathrm{G}=\mathrm{G}_{0} \triangleright \mathrm{G}_{1} \triangleright \ldots \triangleright \mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{r}}=\{\mathrm{e}\}$. Let every quotient group $G_{i} / G_{i+1}, i=0,1,2, \ldots, r-1$ be commutative.

I want to know what symmetric property of the root set of the representation of this Galois group `G` determines that it can have radical solutions.  And what property of the Galois group described by the symmetry of the root set determines that it can be solved by radical. In other words, which of the more in-depth properties between the root sets represented by the Galois group determine that the equation can be solved by radical. It's better to show this relationship clearly with MMA.

Comment: Is not the group property called ["solvable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group)?

Comment: Per the part highlighted in the text (and similarly with other questions you've recently asked), on this site you might get better help if you added a translation. Totally your prerogative, of course, but my sense is that the number of people here who can read Chinese mathematics texts is considerably smaller than the number who can read them in say, English, Spanish, or German

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I want to know what is the special relationship between the root sets of equations with a solvable Galois group? It's better to show this relationship clearly with MMA.

Comment: It's easier on the [Magma Calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/): Enter these four lines: `P<x> := PolynomialRing(IntegerRing());`
`f := x^4-4*x^2-5;`
`G, R, S := GaloisGroup(f);`
`G` -- You can also construct the abelian tower by replacing the last two lines with `K, R := SolveByRadicals(f:Name := "K.");`
`K:Maximal`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I do see the root tower. What is the special relationship between root sets? Can you show it clearly with MMA? After all, a commutative normal subgroup sequence is too abstract.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I want to find a concrete and easy to understand deep-seated relationship, too abstract explanation is not my original intention. This peculiar relationship is best shown clearly by the special relationship between root sets.

Comment: As I've said for many times, simply adding several lines of Mathematica code to a question won't change it to a Mathematica question. Please stop treading on the rule of this site. Vote to migrate.

Comment: @xzczd However, there are not many people who understand MMA in the mathematics zone. The specific calculation is too cumbersome and the amount of calculation is huge, and it can not clearly show which special relationship between the root sets leads to the solvability of the root set.

Comment: I don't know anyone who uses Mma for this sort of calculation, and I still don't know what you're asking for. Give a definition of what it is that you seek, because right now, the only answer I have to give is "solvable," which you rejected. Maybe Lagrange's paper has something you could use. He introduced the notion of substitutions, and I think he worked on a more concrete level than modern abstract algebra. Probably Abel did, too. Maybe Jordan's book, though it's later.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I mainly read [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000030373733&d=A0A41C90DF5DA019D12B83A999E073C6&fenlei=1301090304) and [this textbook](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000015528782&d=1CF316CCE65F831EB54ACB9AB773E1A1&fenlei=1301090304). I know some ideas about Lagrange's resolvent, but I still can't find the specific relationship between the  root sets that make the equation have radical solutions.Thank you very much for your help. Let me think about how to improve this problem.

Comment: What you are asking is not, at this point, a Mathematica-based question. You are looking for a mathematical, possibly algorithmic property or set thereof. Such issues go to a different forum. (If an answer is obtained, and there is difficulty encountered in coding, it might become suitable for this forum.)